# GCC /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGl

Tags: c++, ubuntu, opengl, gcc, linker

eI'm trying to compile a c++ openGL program using libGL and freeglut3. Im trying:

```
g++ main.cpp -w -lglut -lGl -o bin/app
```

or

```
g++ main.cpp -w -lglut -lGL -o bin/app
```

Which results in:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGl
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:16: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

I'm on:

```
Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
```

GCC:

```
gcc version 5.3.1 20160413 (Ubuntu 5.3.1-14ubuntu2)
```

libGL.so

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu$ find libGL.so
libGL.so
```

I installed:

```
freeglut3 freeglut3-dev libglew1.5 libglew1.5-dev libglu1-mesa libglu1-mesa-dev libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dev
```

Am I missing anything? Last time I successfully compiled I was on ubuntu 14.04.

I read somewhere that I should install fglrx-glx but the package is not available.

Update:

```
glxinfo
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics 5500 (Broadwell GT2) 
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 11.2.0
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 3.30
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 11.2.0
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.1 Mesa 11.2.0
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.10
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

My ldconfig.real appears to be empty

Comment: Linux filesystems are case sensitve, Gl != GL.

Comment: I know its Gl for sure, but I tried -lGL and it gave the same error

Comment: No, it is not Gl for sure. Your own post demonstrates that it is called `libGL.so`, and it has always been that way.

Comment: @Nick Try to add `-L` for gcc like this `g++ main.cpp -w -lglut -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lGL -o bin/app`

Comment: @Ivan thanks :) Tried it, still the same error sadly

Comment: Show your Makefile

Comment: @Amadeus http://pastebin.com/73cZ6XvL, the *.cpp isnt in the real one, just a bunch of real .cpp files

Comment: Change `LINKER_FLAGS = -Wall -lm -lpthread -lGl -lglut` to `LINKER_FLAGS = -L/usr/lib -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -Wall -lm -lGL -lglut -lpthread` and run it again

Comment: Same error with that change

Comment: @Nick Run `g++ -dumpmachine` to check if you are trying to link 64-bit library using 32-bit compiler

Comment: @Ivan that returns x86_64-linux-gnu, that's correct right?

Answer (score 5):

> `g++ main.cpp -w -lglut -lGl -o bin/app`

This command is incorrect: you want to link against `libGL`, not `libGl`, so the command should be: `g++ main.cpp -w -lglut -lGL -o bin/app`

UNIX file names are case-sensitive.

> I know its Gl for sure, but I tried -lGL and it gave the same error

You *know* wrong. It should be `-lGL`, and with `libGL.so` present in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` there is *no way* you are getting the same error (possibly you get a different error from `ld` (which matters) but the same error from `make` (which doesn't matter)).

**Update:**

> `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL`

Ok. It *must* be that `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so` is either a dangling symlink, or points to a 32-bit library, or is corrupt in some other way.

**Update 2:**

```
 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so: broken symbolic link to /usr/lib/libGL.so.1.2 2
```

Indeed it's a broken symlink. To fix this, reinstall the package which provides it:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-dev
```

Comment: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:16: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 1

Comment: @Nick What is the output from `file /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so` and `file -L /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so` ?

Comment: hmmm... 

1st:
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so: broken symbolic link to /usr/lib/libGL.so.1.2

2nd:
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so: cannot open `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so' (No such file or directory) I think you might have found my problem

Comment: @Nick "I think you might have found my problem" -- do you have *doubts* that I have? Answer updated.

Comment: No doubts... :P just looking for a way to fix it

Comment: Thanks anway :) With those 2 commands I was able to view what is wrong and fix the symlinks!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I managed to fix it, I don't know if it can be a problem later on, but for now it's going well.

Inside the `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` directory I checked which files the symbolic links made, and I saw that in my case there was no `libGL.so`.In your case it even exists, you can try to delete it and create the symbolic link again.

What I did was create the symbolic link with `libGL.so.1.7.0` (1.7.0 can be changed by the version on your machine).

```sh
sudo ln -s libGL.so.1.7.0 libGL.so
```

I hope this solution works for someone, sorry for the strange English.